# Debug Assertion Failed: string subscript out of range

Tags: string, if-statement, vector, visual-studio-debugging, outofrangeexception

I'm getting a subscript out of range error.
This is the function where it happens:

```
//Load Object Function
int loadObejct(const char *fileName)
{
cout<<"soos";
vector<string*> coord;
vector<coordinate*> vertex;
vector<face*> faces;
vector<coordinate*> normals;
ifstream in(fileName);

if(!in.is_open())
{
    cout<<"no file";
    return 5;
}

char buf[400];

while(!in.eof())
{
    in.getline(buf, 400);
    coord.push_back(new string(buf));
    cout<<"loading";
}
////////////////////////////////////////////where error starts
for(int i = 0; i<coord.size(); i++)
{
    if((*coord[i])[0] =='#' || (*coord[i])[0] == 'g')
    {
        continue;
    }
    else if((*coord[i])[0]=='v' && (*coord[i])[1]==' ' )
    {
        float tmpx, tmpy, tmpz;
        sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(), "v  %f %f %f", &tmpx, &tmpy, &tmpz);
        vertex.push_back(new coordinate(tmpx, tmpy, tmpz));
    }else if((*coord[i])[0]=='v' && (*coord[i])[1]=='n' )
    {
        float tmpx, tmpy, tmpz;
        sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(), "vn %f %f %f", &tmpx, &tmpy, &tmpz);
        normals.push_back(new coordinate(tmpx, tmpy, tmpz));
    }else if((*coord[i])[0]=='f')
    {
        int a, b, c, d, e;
        if(count(coord[i]->begin(), coord[i]->end(), ' ') == 4)
        {
            sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(), "f %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d", &a, &b, &c, &b, &d, &b, &e, &b);
            faces.push_back(new face(b, a, c, d, e));
        }else
        {
            sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(), "f %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d", &a, &b, &c, &b, &d, &b);
            faces.push_back(new face(b, a, c, d));

        }
    }
}///////////////////////////////where error ends
//draw

int num;
num = GL::GenLists(1);
GL::NewList(num, ListMode::Compile);

for(int i = 0; i<faces.size(); i++)
{
    if(faces[i]->four == true)
    {
        GL::Begin(BeginMode::Quads);
        GL::Normal3(normals[faces[i]->faceNum-1]->x, normals[faces[i]->faceNum-1]->y, normals[faces[i]->faceNum-1]->z);
        GL::Vertex3(vertex[faces[i]->faces[0]-1]->x, vertex[faces[i]->faces[0]-1]->y, vertex[faces[i]->faces[0]-1]->z);
        GL::Vertex3(vertex[faces[i]->faces[1]-1]->x, vertex[faces[i]->faces[1]-1]->y, vertex[faces[i]->faces[1]-1]->z);
        GL::Vertex3(vertex[faces[i]->faces[2]-1]->x, vertex[faces[i]->faces[2]-1]->y, vertex[faces[i]->faces[2]-1]->z);
        GL::Vertex3(vertex[faces[i]->faces[3]-1]->x, vertex[faces[i]->faces[3]-1]->y, vertex[faces[i]->faces[3]-1]->z);
        GL::End();
    }else
    {
        GL::Begin(BeginMode::Triangles);
        GL::Normal3(normals[faces[i]->faceNum-1]->x, normals[faces[i]->faceNum-1]->y, normals[faces[i]->faceNum-1]->z);
        GL::Vertex3(vertex[faces[i]->faces[0]-1]->x, vertex[faces[i]->faces[0]-1]->y, vertex[faces[i]->faces[0]-1]->z);
        GL::Vertex3(vertex[faces[i]->faces[1]-1]->x, vertex[faces[i]->faces[1]-1]->y, vertex[faces[i]->faces[1]-1]->z);
        GL::Vertex3(vertex[faces[i]->faces[2]-1]->x, vertex[faces[i]->faces[2]-1]->y, vertex[faces[i]->faces[2]-1]->z);
        GL::End();
    }
}
GL::EndList();

//end draw
for(int i = 0; i<coord.size(); i++)
{
    delete coord[i];
}
for(int i = 0; i<faces.size(); i++)
{
    delete normals[i];
}
for(int i = 0; i<normals.size(); i++)
{
    delete faces[i];
}
for(int i = 0; i<vertex.size(); i++)
{
    delete vertex[i];
}


return 6;
}
```

I marked the area that I narrowed it down to where the problem occurs.
I'm coding is VS2012 and c++/cli.
As you see I'm trying to load data from a .obj file to render a 3D model.
This isn't the complete program.
Please let me know if you see something that I'm missing. :-)

Comment: That sscanf() usage is fingernails on a blackboard.  And wrong, bad format specifier so it corrupts the stack with excellent odds that the `i` variable changes and causes the error.  Stop doing that, you already have access to the members.

Comment: Hmm what you say makes sense...
Any idea what I can use instead of that?